# Create raster from dataframe containing characters as values in R

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to create a `raster` from a `dataframe` in `R`, which contains columns `x`, `y`, `class` and `Notation`. Column `class` contains the class values (characters) for each pixel. The columns of interest are the first 3 columns. I tried three ways of doing it. How can I covert a dataframe with character values into a raster?

Sample data

```
     x          y       class Notation
757293.9519 4074971.494 SHAD  S
757297.0442 4074971.494 GRND  G
757300.1365 4074971.494 SHAD  S
757303.2288 4074971.494 SHAD  S
757306.3211 4074971.494 GRND  G
757309.4134 4074971.494 SHAD  S
757312.5057 4074971.494 PRPU  P
757315.598  4074971.494 PRGLT PR
757318.6903 4074971.494 SHAD  S
757321.7826 4074971.494 GRND  G
757324.8749 4074971.494 ER_SP E
757327.9672 4074971.494 GRND  G
```

Method 1

```
library(raster)

  # Convert df into a raster
  df_rstr = rasterFromXYZ(df)

  # Set CRS    
 projection(df_rstr) = CRS("+proj=utm +zone=11 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

 # Write to file
 writeRaster(df_rstr, "~/df_rstr.tif", overwrite = T)
```

This method creates a `rasterbrick` with three bands, and values ranging from `inf` to `-inf`.

Method 2

```
# Create a SpatialPixelDataFrame
gridded(df) = TRUE

# create raster
df_rstr = raster(df)

# Write to file
writeRaster(df_rstr, "~/df_rstr.tif", overwrite = T)
```

This method converts the `values` from `chr` into `numeric`.

Method 3

```
# Create a SpatialPixelDataFrame
gridded(df) = TRUE

str(df@data)

# create raster
df_rstr = raster(df, "dist")

# Error
Error in `[.data.frame`(x@data, i, j, ..., drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Comment: Are your points on a regular grid? Your sample points certainly aren't. If your real data set is, can you make a sample data set that is too? It only needs to be a few points, can probably make it with a few lines of code.

Comment: @Spacedman, does the sample data look okay now?

Comment: Well it only seems to have one row which breaks `rasterFromXYZ`. Can you simply do `d = data.frame(expand.grid(1:5,1:4))  ; d$class=factor(sample(LETTERS[1:4],nrow(d),TRUE))` to generate something appropriate that's really easy for use to work with? Rather than us having to cut and paste and then `read.table` your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a **gridded** set of X,Y,class coordinates:

```
> d = data.frame(expand.grid(x=1:5,y=1:4))
> d$class=sample(LETTERS[1:4],nrow(d),TRUE)
```

if your character column isn't a factor already, make one that is:

```
> d$fclass=factor(d$class)
```

then make a numeric index column of that factor:

```
> d$iclass = as.numeric(d$fclass)
> head(d)
     x    y class fclass iclass
1    1    1     D      D      4
2    2    1     A      A      1
3    3    1     C      C      3
4    4    1     C      C      3
```

see that D is 4, A is 1 and so on.

Then make a raster with the numbers:

```
r = rasterFromXYZ(d[,c("x","y","iclass")])
```

Finally use those numbers to convert `r` to a factor with the levels from the factor in the data frame:

```
r[] = factor(levels(d$fclass)[r[]])
```

`r` now has *values* from 1 to 4 and a lookup-attribute table that matches the character descriptions:

```
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4, 5, 20  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent     : 0.5, 5.5, 0.5, 4.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : iclass 
values     : 1, 4  (min, max)
attributes :
 ID VALUE
  1     A
  2     B
  3     C
  4     D
```

This is a categorical raster, and is the best you can do with storing "character" values per-cell in a raster.

At this point you may decide that the `terra` package has better support for categorical rasters. For example `plot(r)` doesn't shows the numbers, not the text. You could always use the `tmap` package though: `tm_shape(r) + tm_raster()`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, so does `rasterVis::gplot` support `character` values for raster plots, as I usually stick with `ggplot2` for plotting?

Comment: I don't know, but now you can try it.

Comment: When I export this to `ArcGIS`, the raster `symbology` shows the numerical class values from 1 to 4 (min, max) and the view attribute table is dull. Is there a way to show the character values in symbology and legend in `ArcGIS`? Should I post this as a separate question?

Comment: Yes research it first then post as a question if you can't work it out - make sure you detail how you saved it from R. I don't know anything about ArcGI.